# Error while receiving file changes (Flutter Android)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMvP5.png)

Hello everyone Has anyone encountered such a problem? How to solve it? Downloaded the project from the repository, maybe you need to install another version of java jdk?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujo2I.png)

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.